# Adjusted Price for ETFs

Tags: python, python-3.x, quandl, pandas-datareader

I'm looking for Adjusted Price (price adjusted to factor in dividends and corporate actions) for ETFs, but have not been successful. Is there any free (with limits is fine) data sources out there for this?

**Update:**

A Python API would be ideal, as I am coding in Python for this task. But a different language, or a direct csv file download may potentially work too.

---

I have been getting adjusted stock prices using *pandas_datareader* with quandl as the data source (google and yahoo seem not to work anymore). This **works**:

```
web.DataReader('WIKI/AAPL', 'quandl', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-31')['AdjClose']
```

But it **doesn't work** for ETFs:

```
web.DataReader('WIKI/IVV', 'quandl', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-31')['AdjClose']
```

***RemoteDataError***: Unable to read URL: https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/IVV.csv?start_date=2006-05-01&end_date=2006-05-31&order=asc

*Response Text:
b'code,message\nQECx02, You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again.\n'*

---

I also tried calling the quandl library directly. This **works** ('x' represents my api key):

```
quandl.get('WIKI/AAPL',trim_start='2006-05-01',trim_end = '2006-05-31',authtoken='x')
```

while this **doesn't**:

```
quandl.get('WIKI/IVV',trim_start='2006-05-01',trim_end = '2006-05-31',authtoken='x')
```

***NotFoundError***: (Status 404) (Quandl Error QECx02) You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again.

Comment: Can you provide more info about why you think it doesn't work?  Is there an error message you can include in your question?

Comment: Thanks, edited to include code that works, and code that doesn't with error messages. Sorry I don't know how to make the error messages look better (like indent or color ).

Comment: Not an expert in ETFs but after some searching I found this site: https://www.xignite.com/product/historical-stock-prices/#/productoverview

Specifically, I found the following on the site:

`This API offers historical prices for equities and ETFs trading on more than 50 global exchanges... The API also provides corporate actions such as stock and cash dividends and lets you request split and *dividend adjusted prices*.` (emphasis mine).

Additionally, the site lets you set up a free 7-day trial.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: It may be, I'll try to try it out, but I may fail or it may take me a long time, as it doesn't seem to have a Python API. I'm not familiar with/have other language environments setup right now. I am also looking to utilize the data source in my python code. This can be a backup plan I guess: download with another language, save to csv, and read into python.

Comment: So what could be different about ETF. Did you try a different ETF? Is there a different function to get a list of all the ticker symbols. Maybe IVV isn't in their index, andit's NYSE_IVV or something. Misspelling the ticker was the answer here: https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python/issues/93

Comment: I did try several ETFs. I just tried again, also a few combinations as suggested, like 'WIKI/SPY', 'WIKI/SPY_US', 'WIKI/NYSE_SPY', still the same error. I suspect quandl simply doesn't provide data for ETFs

Comment: Wouldn't the price of the ETF the adjusted close by construct? The traded price of the ETF would represent the value of the fund itself, which would be inclusive of any dividends it received from its underlying stocks, any stock splits would just make the fund own two entities of the same stock, giving tthe fund the same value and so on.

Comment: @ilmarinen, my understanding is, you are right about the stock splits, but ETF pays "dividends" too, mostly passing the stock dividends to the ETF holder, therefore, on the ex-day of an ETF dividend, the ETF market price should drop accordingly to adjust for that. Of course, if it were a non-dividend paying ETF like 'GLD', the market price would be the same as the adjusted price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using https://www.iextrading.com and it has been working perfectly for me. Haven't notice any rate limiting and the data appears to be very clean.

Here is an example call for what you are looking for

```
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/IVV/chart/1m
```

There is also a python module built around this API: https://github.com/addisonlynch/iexfinance

However, I am not sure how far back the data goes...

Last summer I also wrote a API for downloading historical prices from yahoo. It returns price and adjusted price:
https://github.com/AndrewRPorter/yahoo-historical

Comment: Thanks, I tried the python API. It does work on ETFs, however, the prices it gave seems just the regular market prices, not the "adjusted price" - **please correct me if wrong**. I am already able to get market prices with pandas_datareader from various sources, such as google or morningstar.

Comment: Slightly off topic: Even though this does not answer this question, still a good data source to have for other purposes. To address "not sure how far back the data goes", I think it goes for the previous 5 years, because when I tried older dates, I got the error message: **ValueError: Invalid date specified. Must be within past 5 years.** Hope this is useful.

Comment: @Indominus I wrote this last year to scrape yahoo for adjust close, I should have added it with my original psot: https://github.com/AndrewRPorter/yahoo-historical, I updated the post to add this. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Interesting, it works. Just curious (or greedy), is there any method in your package to know the earliest available date for each ticker or does it have to be try-error?

Comment: Also, this solution seems to have nothing to do with your original iextrading part. May I ask why you "have been using iextrading" while you have this home-brewed API that works even better?

Comment: I use iextrading for quotes and the yahoo-historical for historical data

Comment: data.getDividends() seems to return a DataFrame not order by Date (ex-date), is that intended?

Comment: Nope. That however, is the beauty of open source. Does it work for what you need though?

Comment: OK, that's cool, just trying to do some simple sanity check on your package. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Indominus I am the author of the iexfinance Python wrapper for IEX. Feel free to PM me if you have any further questions

Answer (score 0):

So being a stocks newb might be off but https://github.com/iexg/IEX-API/issues/224 seems to be asking for adjusted prices from iex data.  No resolution yet on that package but if the adjusted price is just price - any dividend paid out that day, you could pull dividend info from https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/ivv/dividends/5y for ex and then adjust what you get from your pandas-datareader returns accordingly.  Also, note that you can get more fields from the iex data than the datareader exposes.  I just took the code off https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/iex/daily.py and commented out the 2 lines that subset the dataframe by the list values

```
values = ["open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"]
df = df[values].
```

Then when I call

```
ix = IEXDailyReader(symbols='IVV', start='2016-05-01', end = '2017-05-31')
```

I see all the fields but oddly I see no diff in volume and adjusted volume even for days that there were dividends paid out.